# save to text from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to save my dataframe which consists of 2 colums into a text file,I get this error of mismatch between array dtype,any suggestions on what i could do?

[image: The error Image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df.to_csv('hopefully.txt', index=False, sep=' ', header=None)
```

For the file to be saved without a comma, use the `sep=' '`. To cut off the column title, `header=None`.

Comment: thanks,that works but i was hoping to save the file without the comma,in this file there is a comma in between, i need just a space in between,what do i do get that?

Comment: @Abien Fred Agarap - Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a million man!! once i get 15 rep points ,ill make sure to come back and accept.